# Query a many to may relationship with Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a many to many relationship defined in my DB between User and Clinic tables. The database wasn't created using EF but I generated the DB model classes using EF. M-M relationship is usually created with EF by having collection object property of the of the linked classes defined within those classes but here I have an indirect relationship. Both User and Clinic models have UserClinic collection object instead of pointing directly to the other class.

Here's how the data objects are defined:

**User**

```
    public User()
    {
        this.UserClinics = new HashSet<UserClinic>();
    }

    public long UsersID { get; set; }
    public string AspNetUsersID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CreateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserClinic> UserClinics { get; set; }
}
```

**Clinic**

```
public Clinic()
    {
        this.UserClinics = new HashSet<UserClinic>();
        this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
    }

    public long ClinicID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> NetworkID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CreateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Network Network { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserClinic> UserClinics { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

**UserClinic**

```
public partial class UserClinic
{
    public long UsersID { get; set; }
    public long ClinicID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CreateBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

What's the best way to query objects so I get something to the effect of:

```
var cliniclist = user.clinics.toList();
```

or

```
var user.clinics.Add(clinicList);
```

Comment: Some examples https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/

Answer (score 1):

To select you just need to select the `UserClinics` collection and then select the `Clinic` property from it:

```
var clinics = user.UserClinics.Select(x => x.Clinic);
```

To add:

```
user.UserClinics.Add(new UserClinic { ClinicID = 1, Clinic = new Clinic { ... } });
```